# Pass dynamic value to localization JSON file in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, dynamic, localization, laravel-blade

In my Laravel app, I am doing localization with JSON files instead of PHP files. I am following this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys) and searching for a way to pass a dynamic value.

In `i18n` in React, it is done like this...

In `ja.json`

```
{
    "searchResultText":"{{count}} 件表示. ({{rangeStart}} - {{rangeEnd}})"
}
```

While using it in JSX...

```
i18n.t('searchResultText', {count: data.count, rangeStart: data.rangeStart, rangeEnd: data.rangeEnd});
```

But how can I pass dynamic value from blade templates and how to use it in the JSON file?

Laravel version: 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ja.json`

```
{
    "searchResultText":":count 件表示. (:rangeStart - :rangeEnd)"
}
```

In blade template

```
{{ __('searchResultText', ['count' => 'Dynamic count value here', 'rangeStart' => 'Dynamic rangeStart value here', 'rangeEnd' => 'Dynamic rangeEnd value here']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can pass **dynamic value to localization JSON file in Laravel**

en.json

`{ "Welcome to our website, :Name": "Bienvenue sur notre site, :Name" }`

ru.json

`{ "Welcome to our website, :Name": "Добро пожаловать на наш сайт, :Name" }`

blade.php

`{{ __('Welcome to our website, :Name', ['name' => 'amanda']) }}`